# Canopy + easygui

Tags: canopy, easygui

I would like to use my Canopy editor with "easygui", but I can't install it from the package Manager.
Is there any way I could do it from shell without damaging anything?
Thanks a lot in advance!

edit
simplest program:
    import easygui
    path = easygui.fileopenbox()

I get a big report and no execution...
For example:

0   CoreFoundation                      0x92e88471 __raiseError + 193
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x9b7c4091 objc_exception_throw + 162
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x92e8ccb3 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
...

84 Python                              0x00011110 PyObject_CallObject + 32

85  libpyside-python2.7.1.2.2.dylib     0x0054ca19

_ZN6PySide13SignalManager20callPythonMetaMethodERK11QMetaMethodPPvP7_objectb + 121

Comment: I apologize if you already try this, but how about: pip install --upgrade easygui

Answer (score 0):

No problem, no harm, to install it following https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-Python-from-the-command-line

I have no information about how well it will work. You can use it from a Canopy Command Prompt (Windows) or Terminal (OSX/Linux). If you use it from inside the Canopy GUI, be sure to change the Pylab backend (in Preferences/Python) to Inline (SVG) as it will conflict with the Interactive backends.

Comment: Thank You very much. I tried exactly that, but it seems not to be working. I get the biggest report I've ever seen and the code is not executed. I edit my question. Thank You anyway :)